# Apache takes me to same site with different domains

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, https

When I try to navigate to my site any domain I enter under https it takes me to the site specified in the VirtualHost config provided. I have setup the ServerName but it still doesn't work. So if I enter https://storage.example.com/ it takes me to the site as expected but when I enter anything else such as https://ab.example.com/ it still takes me to the previous site. Why does this happen?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName storage.example.com
        #Redirect permanent / https://storage.example.com/
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^storage.example.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://storage.example.com$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        Alias /files /var/www/files
        ServerName storage.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/

        <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
                Options +FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride All

                <IfModule mod_dav.c>
                        Dav off
                </IfModule>

                SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
                SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
        </Directory>

        # SSL
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.example.com/fullchain.pem

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You only have a single host configured in that file. How is apache supposed to know what to do with the other domains?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I didn't know that. How can I send the user to a 502 error page when the user goes to an unknown domain.

Comment: Please read the linked question. It's explained there.